# Is there a way to limit the number of children in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a firebase into which i'm pushing quite regularly, much like a chat, and i'm concerned about the number of children gathering in the firebase. They are all removed when all the connections are gone but is there a way to limit the number of them in there?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean limit/prevent the writing of new data; or, when it's being read back out?

Comment: limit/prevent writing new data, what I really need is a way to remove the oldest child from it before adding the new one.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement something like this using a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). If you wanted to have no more than 50 nodes, you could have children of a node referenced as /0, /1, /2, ... /49, and write to those as data is being generated. Using a [`transaction()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html) you could then have another location in Firebase keep track if current 'start' and 'end'. Priorities could also be used in conjunction with this approach to keep this ordered (for example, by timestamp.)  This approach would also have the benefit of not having to prune the data as it grew.

We don't currently have a mechanism to enforce this using server-side security rules, but I've made a note of it in our internal tracker.

Comment: brilliant! Thanks for this, i'll try to implement something now.